# Blocking other UEFI Runtime Services tasks from running

Tags: c, linux, task, jobs, uefi

Is there a way to block other UEFI RT services from running when I execute a Linux program that calls the UEFI RT service? Either from the linux side or from the UEFI side is ok (Both are written in C).

That is, when my program executes, it calls UEFI RT service to perform task A. I don't know what other tasks are. There may be ABCDEFG tasks that call the RT service. However, I only want A to be executed.

The reason behind this is that some other RT service(s) is causing data corruption to the output of my program but I don't know which one. And I have no access to the source code.

Comment: Which RT service are you calling? What kind of data corruption do you observe? Why do you think that the corruption happens because some other runtime service is called? Or is it the same RT service is called at the same time? Need more clarity in the description and more info. One way to block RT services, would be to hook them with a UEFI app.

Answer (score 0):

In general, UEFI runs on cooperative multitasking, so there should not be interruptions to the UEFI code, unless code with higher IRQ needs to run. that also should not create interference.

probably your problem lies elsewhere.